# Why isn't up-casting automatic in f#

Tags: casting, f#

I was implementing a C# interface in F# that looked something like:

```
public interface IThings
{
    Stream ThingsInAStream()
}
```

My implementation looked something like:

```
type FSharpThings() = 
    interface IThings with
       member this.ThingsInAStream() = 
           let ms = new MemoryStream()
           // add things to stream
           ms
```

Now I get the message:

```
The expression was expected to have type 
  Stream
but here has type
  MemoryStream
```

I don't understand MemoryStream ***IS*** a Stream I know that I can cast it to as stream like:

```
ms :> Stream
```

Same goes for `[|"string"|]` and `IEnumerable<string>` it implements the interface and I can explicitly cast to it BUT it doesn't work automatically.

Why does this work?

```
let things:(IEnumerable<'a> -> 'a) = (fun f -> f.First())

let thing= things([|"";""|])
```

This is also automatic upcasting!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the answer from Nicolas is generally right. Allowing automatic up-casting *everywhere* in the language would cause problems for type inference.

In principle, the compiler could try looking for a common base type of the types returned in different branches, but this is not as easy as it sounds:

- First, should it return the most specific type or some other type? (The compiler could find the most specific, but perhaps you actually want to return something a bit more general than what could be inferred from your code - so specifying that explicitly is useful.)
- Second, things get difficult with interfaces. Imagine that two branches return two different classes both implementing interfaces `IA` and `IB`. How does the compiler decide whether the return type should be `IA` or `IB`, or perhaps `obj`? (This is a big problem, because it significantly affects how the code can be used!) See [this snippet](http://fssnip.net/ix) for more details.

However, there is one place where this is not a problem and F# compiler allows it. That is, when passing argument to a function or a method - in this case, the compiler knows what the desired type is and so it only needs to *check* that the upcast is allowed; it does not need to *infer* what upcast to insert. As a result, the type inference is not affected and so the compiler can insert an upcast. That is why the following works:

```
// The example from the question
let first (items:seq<'a>) = items |> Seq.head
let thing = first [|"";""|]

// Even simpler example - passing string as object
let foo (a:obj) = a 
foo "123"
```

Here, the argument is `array<string>` and the function expects `seq<string>`. The compiler knows what upcast to insert (because it knows the target type) and so it does that.

Comment: One could say in that case the compiler knows the return type in practice as well, since appending :> _ would make it work. Still a guess though, and the rule looks like there is no upcast based on a guess.

Comment: @nicolas Do you mean in the case with `IA` and `IB` interfaces? If you add `:> _` you get an error _"error FS0013: The static coercion from type First to 'a involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Static coercions are not allowed on some types. Further type annotations are needed."_

Comment: not if you write "let test : IA" first, which might be closer to what is here : we know the return type should be Stream.

Comment: @nicolas True. If you always specify type explicitly _somewhere_ than it will work (just like when calling a function or a method - at least method that is not overloaded). But again - I think it would make the system more complex (e.g. perhaps you'd need some priority to make sure explicit annotations are always preferred in the constraint solving)

Comment: I think so as well, and for little reward if not confusion elsewhere.

Comment: As a minor additional note, there are a few other places where something that looks like upcasting takes place.  For instance, `let o:obj = first [1; "1"]`.  List and array literals have some extra logic for unifying the types of their constituents.

Answer (score 11):

This is the counterparty of having a powerful type inference mechanism : 
By having everything explicit, it is *easier* for the compiler to reason about what is true or not.

It feels strange at first, as we are relying so much on those conversions in other relaxed langage.

But practically it turns out to be a strength overall, and allow both the type inference mentioned, as well as promotes good programming practices like programing to the interface VS the concrete implementation.

One useful construct in cases, where it feels plain superfluous, is to add the cast

```
//The cast will be determined by the compiler, because of _
result :> _
```

Comment: Doesn't programming against the interface as you say result in code littered with `:> _` ? Since every function that returns an interface in fact returns another object that implements that interface. I don't think it promotes programming to the interface at all since the type gets infered it'll infer the concrete type instead of the the interface.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further? I've read your answer a couple times now and it'll probably make sense to people familiar with f# but it doesn't make sense to me. Somehow it feels like the type inference mechanism only works one way.

Comment: it is true that the type inference will only use explicit information.  I would not call this one way though as this consistency flow in every way.

Comment: Ok I accepted your answer could you update your answer and explain your first sentence a bit further.

Comment: Could you cite an example of where inferring a "greatest common" base type among branches of an expression actually undermines other features of F#'s type inference? My feeling was always that such a feature was not implemented due to philosophy or complexity (time), not technical.

Comment: @StephenSwensen I actually have the same feeling. I think it would *practically*, in the implementation of inference, be complex and potentially interact negatively with other features, leading to slowness .

Comment: To give an example where things would not work nicely, imagine that two branches return two different classes both implementing interfaces `IA` and `IB`. How does the compiler decide whether the return type should be `IA` or `IB`, or perhaps `obj`? (This is a big problem, because it significantly affects how the code can be used!)

Comment: @nicolas actually when I said "time" I meant "$ cost to implement", I don't suspect it would actually have a super notable impact on the speed of compilation.

Comment: @TomasPetricek based on what albert jan question, it would look up the return type I and cast it to stream. what you say is both IA and IB here inherit from that type I but might bind to different methods ?

Comment: @TomasPetricek that is a good example, but I think it would be reasonable to infer the return type as `obj` and emit a *warning* suggesting that a type annotation be used (either on the function definition, or one of the branches) to resolve the ambiguity (which would be consistent with somewhat similar scenarios where F# infers generic type parameters to be constrained to `obj`).

Comment: Note that here we have an additional piece of information : the return type is being declared as Stream, or IA. let test : IA = 
  if 1 = 1 then First()
  else Second() might be more faithful to the question

Comment: Two quick points: Yes, I think this specific snippet is quite clear case, but I think it is hard to integrate it with the type inference in a uniform non-ad-hoc way (though I agree it could be done) @StephenSwensen I agree - but I think the aim is to keep F# type inference simple and predictable as much as possible. This is a key usability concern (and there are already cases when it confuses people).

Comment: A nice alternative to 'result :> _' is 'upcast result'.

Comment: I think, automatic up-casting is an implementation of Polymorphism and as such is fundamental to the notion of objects. Interfaces and inheritance hierarchies are merely a mechanism for grouping feature stipulations and evolving type descriptions. The useful type remains their totality and not merely a collection of incidental concepts. In particular, a type is not merely a specific definition some place in the code but a collection of definitions as grouped and prioritized by it's hierarchy. In this respect, perhaps the compiler's symbol table is being a bit lazy in not holding the group def.