# Compiler overriding type definitions (generics) in F#

Tags: generics, f#, type-inference

Scenario 1

```
let map = Dictionary<string,obj>()
map.Add("1",10)
map.Add("2",10L)
map.Add("3","10")
```

This complies fine

Scenario 2

```
let map = Dictionary<string,(unit -> obj)>()
map.Add("1",fun() -> 10)
map.Add("2",fun() -> 10L)
map.Add("3",fun() -> "10")
```

Here the compiler says that it excepted obj but found int when it encounters `10`

Scenario 3

```
let map = Dictionary<string,(unit -> 'a)>()
map.Add("1",fun() -> 10)
map.Add("2",fun() -> 10L)
map.Add("3",fun() -> "10")
```

Here the compiler accepts the first entry but it causes 'a to be constrained to int which causes the next two entries to fail because they are not int

1st question: Why does it compile in scenario 1 when it does not in scenario 2?

2nd question: Is there anyway to prevent 'a to be constrained in scenario 3 or is there a certain pattern that can be used that would enable having different types (function types specifically like in this example) in a collection in F#?

The only thing the values (obj / 'a) are to be used for is being an argument for `println "%A"` which I fail to see why it can't be.

Comment: For scenario 2, you can use `box` to fix the upcasting to `obj`. E.g., instead of `10` write `box 10`.

Comment: This is also related to the following recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807839/why-isnt-up-casting-automatic-in-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scenario 1, the compiler automatically upcasts the argument to `map.Add` from `int` etc to `obj`, because it can see that `map.Add` expects `obj`.

In scenario 2, it can't do that because there is no upcast available from `unit -> int` to `unit -> obj` - you couldn't make the conversion by manually inserting `upcast` around the function.

In theory the compiler could change the body of the function instead, but the automatic insertion of casts is purely local at the point where the call to `map.Add` is made.

You can't prevent `'a` being constrained in scenario 3, because the runtime requires that specific objects have a specific type - even if you only use the values in a particular way, the compiler and runtime don't do the kind of global analysis that would be needed to see that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
Based on Jack P. answer i assume the best way to handle this would be to use obj and box every entry?

Comment: @Arkuray You don't need to use `obj` *and* `box` -- just `box`.

Comment: You could use a generic function to allow the client code to submit any `unit->'a` and then wrap that in a new function that does the boxing: `let map = Dictionary<string,unit->obj>()` and `let add key (f:unit->'a) = map.Add(key, fun () -> box <| f())`