# Why is automatic upcasting fine in Swift

Tags: swift, types, casting, type-conversion

In Swift, we can create a custom UICollectionViewCell as follows:

`class MyCell : UICollectionViewCell {}`

Next, if we have the method:

`override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {}`

which expects us to return a `UICollectionViewCell`, we can return an instance of `MyCell` without any issue.

In F#, we must first do the following cast:

`thisCell :> UICollectionViewCell` or else F# will complain that we are returning an object of the wrong type. I understand that this is an issue in F# related to type inference, as described here: [Why isn't up-casting automatic in f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807839/why-isnt-up-casting-automatic-in-f)

Why is this not an issue for Swift, which also uses type inference?

Comment: Lots of OO languages let you do this. It's a simple reference to a class higher up the class hierarchy.

Comment: This is basic OOP - you can use a subclass wherever a superclass is needed.

Answer (score 1):

That question you reference appears to be having trouble in F# inferring the correct type of some property merely through through the declaration of conformance to some interface. `IThings` is an interface to which `FSharpThings` conforms.

It strikes me that the equivalent in Swift would be:

```
class A { }

class B: A { }

protocol MyProtocol {
    var value: A { get set }
}

class Test: MyProtocol {
    var value = B()
}
```

This results in a warning that `Test` does not conform to the protocol.

You can see the problem here: What type should the compiler infer for `value`? If it did the standard inference, it would infer that `value` in `Test` is a `B` and that `Test` should feel free to call `B` methods. But what if something else tried to change `value` to some `A` instance, like the protocol says it can: Then `Test` methods calling `B` methods on `value` would fail.

The other potential alternative would be for the compiler to infer that `value` is of type `A`. This would be complicated for the compiler and, worse, confusing for the programmer writing code for `Test`. Any programmer glancing at the code would be confused why they can't call `B` methods because they'd logically assume it was type `B` on the basis of the declaration. It would be a mess.

So, the compiler is going to require you to explicitly declare it as type `A`. One solution is to manually upcast to eliminate any ambiguity:

```
class Test: MyProtocol {
    var value = B() as A
}
```

Or, more natural in Swift, one could explicitly declare the type to conform to the protocol:

```
class Test: MyProtocol {
    var value: A = B()
}
```

The `cellForItemAt` situation is different. You are not trying to have the compiler infer the type of some property. It knows precisely what `cellForItemAt` returns, and all the compiler cares about is whether whatever is returned by this method is a `UICollectionViewCell`. It, quite correctly, doesn't care if it's a `UICollectionViewCell` or a subclass of that.

Bottom line, the `cellForItemAt` scenario is very different than the one presented in that other question.

Answer (score 0):

It's Swift's object-oriented design. I don't know how things work in F#, but that's not the question here.

The inheritance model of Swift is quite plain and similar to real-life: Any subclass `B`of a class `A` is also an instance of the class `A`.

Same as in real-life: You're basically a `Mammal`. Consider this the base class for this (quite odd) example. But you're also an instance of type `Human`. And being a `Human` doesn't mean you're not a `Mammal` anymore:

```
Mammal
|--- Human
     |--- Man
     |--- Woman
```

Now take that concept to programming with Swift:

```
UICollectionViewCell
|--- MyCell
|--- AnotherCell
```

It's now perfectly fine that `MyCell(...) is UICollectionViewCell` equals `true` and a `MyCell` instance is accepted as a return value considering the above model. Just don't confuse between an object being an instance of a class and this class being its "most precise / downstream" type.

Comment: I know very well how OOP design works and what subclasses are. I think that if you open the link I was linking to and read the accepted question there you'll see why I'm confused why this isn't an issue in swift but is in F#

Comment: @Alk Your question asked with it isn't an issue in Swift. Why not ask about Java or Objective-C or the many other languages where it also is not an issue?

Comment: @Alk What Swift does is the very basic mirroring of OOP principles. What F# does to make compiling easier is actually a variation, what Swift does is the natural thing to do. That's what I wanted to express.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple: Swift supports Object Oriented Programming, and thus it honours one of the OOP principles - polymorphism. And this is exactly what a `UICollectionView` does: in treats all `UICollectionViewCell` instances and it subclasses instances the same way, referring to the base class when doing operations.

Since a subclass inherits all members of the parent class, it's logical to be able to use it wherever the superclass is needed.

Note that this feature is unrelated to type inference, the ability of using a subclass instance where a superclass is related to type compatibility, not type inference.